# How to find the date closer to another date using mysql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, date

I want to retrieve a record which has a date field whose value is closer to a given date.How should I proceed?

Below is the table,

```
id |employeeid|region |startdate  |enddate  |
 1  1234         abc   2014-11-24  2015-01-17
 2  1234         xyz   2015-01-18  9999-12-31
```

Here, I should retrieve the record whose enddate is closer to the startdate of another record say,'2015-01-18', so it should retrieve the 1 st record.I tried the following queries

1.

```
SELECT l.region
FROM ABC.location l where l.EmployeeId=1234
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF('2015-01-18',l.Enddate) );
```

2.

```
SELECT l.region
FROM ABC.location l where l.EmployeeId=1234
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF(l.Enddate,'2015-01-18') );
```

But, none of them is working. Kindly help me in this.

Thanks,
Poorna.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT l.region, ABS( DATEDIFF('2015-01-18',l.Enddate) ) as resultDiff FROM ABC.location l where l.EmployeeId=1234 ORDER BY resultDiff");
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(1); 
List result = query.list();
```

Comment: what if that returns back 11 rows ?

Comment: add Limit 1 to the end

Comment: Thanks Neil. But in hibernate, 'LIMIT 1' condition does not seen to work.Then it retrieves all the records from the database.Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Hi Niel,I tried this as well.But I am getting an exception with the stack trace as follows, "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here"

Comment: Hi Niel,I tried this as well.But I am getting an exception with the stack trace as follows, "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here". I generally use hibernatetemplate to create queries.Can you suggest me like how can I write the same using hibernatetemplate?  Thanks, Poorna.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Unix timestamps are expressed as a number of seconds since 01 Jan 1970, so if you subtract one from the other you get the difference in seconds. The difference in days is then simply a matter of dividing by the number of seconds in a day:

(date_modified - date_submitted) / (24*60*60)
or

(date_modified - date_submitted) / 86400

get the minimum of them.
refer this question it may be helpful::::[Selecting the minimum difference between two dates in Oracle when the dates are represented as UNIX timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399933/selecting-the-minimum-difference-between-two-dates-in-oracle-when-the-dates-are)